# Why Employer is Angry Because I am about to Resign?

Tags: management, resignation

I took a few unjustified absences lately to interview.

My employer suspects my imminent departure.

I have not been assigned any tasks lately.

Is it common for bosses to be angry when an employee wants to leave?

Shouldn't they ask why the would want to leave instead and be attentive?

Comment: If you think the reasons you want to leave can be fixed, you should try to fix them prior to (or in addition to) searching for a new job (but you might still be able to do that). Since it seems you haven't, your manager may just be assuming you believe they can't be fixed. Not assigning long-term tasks to someone who won't be sticking around makes business sense, that doesn't sound like anger to me.

Comment: How did your employer knew you were on another interview? Did they find out or did you tell them?

Comment: This employer has a high turnover rate, and mostly, when people do what I did, they end up resigning, as they were hired elsewhere.

Comment: @Isaiah3015, it also could be through networking, who knows.

Comment: What if you weren't looking to leave? Would you still like the boss to ask why you want to leave? You somewhat want the boss to assume that unjustified absences implies going to interviews. I am confused about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: You are making too many assumptions in your post. If you took leave appropriately (with proper notice), the absences were not unjustified. Everyone needs time off now and again for personal reasons. Not getting assigned tasks does not necessarily mean your employer is "angry."

Answer (score 3):

> Is it common for bosses to be angry when an employee wants to leave?

Can't tell for sure, but it would make sense for a boss to be disappointed or worried by the prospect idea of an employee wanting to leave, as this usually means that they will have to quickly take over his/her tasks, do a lot of paperwork for the termination, start seeking for possible candidates to fill the job and return to normal workloads, etc.

Not necessarily is it common for them to be *angry*, but surely they won't be *happy* about it.

> Shouldn't they ask why the would want to leave instead and be attentive?

Well, maybe they could. But what I recommend is that **you clarify this situation to your boss, instead of waiting him to approach you**.

Waiting for him to ask you may be dangerous, as they could assume many things. It is better if you just clear those doubts immediately, by saying something like *"Hello Boss, I have had some unjustified absences lately, sorry, had some problems that I couldn't handle. Promise this won't happen again, and will try to give you a heads up if I feel like something is getting our of my control."*

Comment: I have always told my boss what bothers me. Now the "CEO" (boss's boss) is not happy and won't even say hello.

Comment: In Spanish we have a saying that translates to something like "You are not a gold coin to be of everyone's liking" ... probably you will be liked and disliked by many people in your life. Not to diminish your comment, but the CEO is not your direct boss; you should worry more about your own boss.

Comment: Do you advise him to lie? He clearly looks for a different job and you say he should tell his boss that his absences didn't have anything to do with job seeking?

Comment: @Ans in no way I said anything about lying, just not to wait for boss to magically understand OP's reasons... OP may be looking for new job, but still has this one and has to be clear and justify absences with Boss. He can then present his Notice on the expected period, but its not good idea to say you want to quit before you actually do or have another offer ready.